# Why can I not call a public method of a created object?

Tags: java, jtextfield

When I am trying to run this Java program to make a JTextField:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class TextField1 extends JFrame{
  private final int WIDTH = 320; 
  private final int HEIGHT = 250; 
  private FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(); 
  private JTextField myOutput = new JTextField();

  public TextField1() {
    super("My TextField Example");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT); 
    setLayout(flow);
    JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(20);
    add(myOutput);
    setVisible(true); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
  }

  public void createGUI(){
    myOutput.setText("I am a text field showing output!");
    myOutput.setEditable(false);
  }

  public static void main(String[]args) {
 TextField1 myTextField = new TextField1(); 
 myTextField.createGUI();
 System.out.println(myTextField.myOutput.getText());
  }
}
```

It seems as if it does not register the createGUI() method. Can you explain why this is?

Comment: I highly recommend changing the title of your post, sounds more like a rant than an answerable question. Also, post the relevant code in the question **here**.

Comment: This code works fine. I can run it as is.

Comment: "It seems as if it does not register the createGUI() method." What makes you think that? Are you getting a compile error? A runtime error? Something happens but it's not what you expect? If so, what happened and what do you think should have happened instead?

Comment: Define "can't call the method", I bet you *can*. I bet it's more that you've hidden your instance variable with your method local in the ctor so when you *do* call it you're not updating the widget you think you are.

Comment: this code works fine for me...what were you expecting it to do?

Comment: @NawedShaikh It's unlikely it's working as the OP expects, however, because the text field that's being updated isn't the one added to the frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the constructor, you are creating a new variable called `myOutput`, which is not the same as the instance variable declared above. `JTextField myOutput` should be `myOutput`

EDIT:

You declare a *method-local* variable `myOutput` and add it to your frame. `createGUI()` uses the *instance* variable declared at the top of the class, therefore it does not affect the `TextField` in the frame.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RossDrew It does, just not directly. That said, the question asked the wrong thing, because it wasn't debugged or logged to show that the method was actually executing.

Comment: @RossDrew updated the answer to explain what was wrong.

Comment: I've removed my downvote but this still doesn't answer why `createGUI` can't be called.  It can be called so the question is invalid anyway.

Comment: @RossDrew Actually he didn't asked the question correctly..he wanted the TextField on the frame to contain the text...

Comment: I see.  It really was badly worded then :) up vote for Kung Fu interpretation

Answer (score 0):

I am just extending the answer which was provided by blueygh2. The main problem is that :

 you have not given the size of the JTextField in the class which will be 0 by default

```
private JTextField myOutput = new JTextField();//no size specified
```

Also in constructor you are Declaring another JTextField with same name that will be eligible for Garbage collection after Object Creation :

```
JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(20);
```

**Now there are 2 solutions :**
1>Specify the size of JTextField in class definition like :

```
JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(20); // new object created for JTextField
```

2> Do not create a new JTextField Object in Constructor like :

```
myOutput = new JTextField(20);
```